# can't get string value from inheritance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can't get string value even tho in my Parent class it works properly and now that I'm getting it . It won't get its value

this my parent class

```
public class GameManagerRevamped : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string finalAnswer;
    public string TryInheritance;
    public virtual void firstButtonClicked()
    {
    Debug.Log(TryInheritance);
    }

public virtual void GetValuebtn()
    {
    TryInheritance = finalAnswer;
    Debug.Log("this is working" +TryInheritance +finalAnswer);
    }
}
```

Child Class

```
 public class FableScript : GameManagerRevamped
 {

       public override void firstButtonClicked()
       {   
           finalAnswer += "a";
           base.firstButtonClicked();
       }
 }
```

Comment: Are you overriding and calling this `GetValuebtn` at any point in time during execution?

Comment: Please give some information about how are you printing the values.

Comment: public TextMeshProUGUI GetValue;

Comment: public virtual void GetValuebtn()
    {
        TryInheritance = finalAnswer;
        Debug.Log("this is working" +TryInheritance +finalAnswer);
    }

Comment: No i'm not overriding the GetValuebtn I just put it there to test whether I get the values in the child class

Comment: What output do you get?  Can you include the lines of code where you call the method?  How do you initialize the instance?

Comment: This `TryInheritance` field is never assigned any value until this method `GetValuebtn` is called, so try calling that method from derived class first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetValuebtn()` method is never called therefore `TryInheritance` is always "".

I think you want to do the following:

```
public virtual void firstButtonClicked()
{
    GetValuebtn();
    Debug.Log(TryInheritance);
}
```

Comment: In Unity the serialized fields are initialized with a default value ... so `TryInheritance` should be `""` not `null`